# Merge sort on structs not working

Tags: c++, struct, mergesort

I am performing a merge sort on a struct.
The sort is performed on the destination cities which is an array
When I tried it with plain arrays it worked.It doesnt work for structures though :(

```
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <sstream>   // for std::istringstream
#include <cstring>    // for std::string and std::getline
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 30
#define WORD 3


typedef struct node{
int nodeId;
char destCity[MAX];
char arrCity[MAX];
int time;
}NODE;

typedef struct edge{
 int adjoin;
int distance;
}EDGE;

typedef struct graph{
NODE cityNode[MAX];
EDGE e[MAX][MAX];
}GRAPH;

GRAPH graph,graphCpy,Temp;
GRAPH currentArray;


void MergeA(int low ,int mid , int high)
{
int i = low, j = mid+1 , k = low;

while(i <= mid && j <= high)
{
    if(currentArray.cityNode[i].destCity <= currentArray.cityNode[j].destCity)
    {
    strcpy(Temp.cityNode[k].destCity,currentArray.cityNode[i].destCity);
            i++;
    }
    else
    {
            strcpy(Temp.cityNode[k].destCity,currentArray.cityNode[j].destCity);
        Temp[k].assign(currentArray[j]);
            j++;
    }
    k++;
}
if(i > mid )
{
    for(int h = j ;h <= high ; h++ )
    {

    strcpy(Temp.cityNode[k].destCity,currentArray.cityNode[h].destCity);
        k++;

    }
}
else
    for(int h = i; h<= mid ; h++ )
    {

strcpy(Temp.cityNode[k].destCity,currentArray.cityNode[h].destCity);

    k++;

    }
 for(int i = low; i <= high ; i++){

    strcpy(currentArray.cityNode[i].destCity,Temp.cityNode[i].destCity);
}


}
void MergeSortA(int low , int high)
{

int mid = 0;
if(low < high)
{
    mid = low + (high-low)/2;
cout<<"beforemerge"<<endl;
    MergeSortA(low , mid);
    MergeSortA(mid+1,high);
    MergeA(low,mid,high);

}
}
int main(){
std::ifstream infile("theWords.txt");
    std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile,(line)) && count<30){
    std::istringstream iss(line);
            if ((iss) >>graph.cityNode[count].destCity >> graph.cityNode[count].arrCity  >> graph.cityNode[count].time){
graph.cityNode[count].nodeId = count ;
count++;
}
graphCpy= graph;
currentArray= graphCpy;
MergeSortA(0,count);
for(int i = 0; i <= count ; i++){
    cout << currentArray.cityNode[i].destCity <<endl;

    }
}
```

I input values into graph copy which is then given to currentArray!!

Comment: What did you discover when you tried to debug the program? Step through it like by line comparing the values in memory against what you think they should be.

Comment: THe problem was when I tried it with an array it sorts it fine with the logic. Just when I convert it to a struct it didnt sort but gave me the unsorted input

Comment: You don't show us how you populate `graphCpy`. Is a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) too much to ask?

Comment: I am sorry. I have added the entire code now.

Comment: "It doesnt work"? Explain. You should also fix your indentation.

Comment: It doesnt sort the destination cities in ascending order. I have tried to implement merge sort.

Comment: It also doesn't *compile*. You have subscript operators for object classes that don't support them. `Temp[k].assign(currentArray[j]);` where `Temp` is a global of type `GRAPH` doesn't compile. And your mix of standard C++ and C *seriously* needs to be resolved, starting with the headers and working down.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that you can reasonably compare arrays of characters using `a < b`. That is not the case. You'll need to have a look at `strcmp()` or, preferable, use `std::string` instead in the first place. Personally, I would also strong recommend to make the merge sort algorithms *entirely* independent on any particular structure and make sure that I can reasonably swap my nodes around.

Comment: I tried it with strcmp. It gives me the same unsorted input as the output :(

Comment: Still, by dropping the use of `strcmp` you are only creating an additional problem for yourself. _Programming by guessing does not work._

Comment: OMG it worked. The problem was with not using strcmp. I didnt do strcmp(,,) <=0.
Thanks so much @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: So... I guess the rest of us will foster our support. +1, Dietmar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @WhozCraig. WIll definitely work on it

Comment: @WhozCraig: thanks! :) I guess, some people don't quite get how the site is intended to work but I have long ago decided that I don't care (when I was active in UseNet, long before stackoverflow): teaching people how to solve their problems is a great approach to learning.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Without a doubt. I've learned a *ton* from guys like you, Lightness, Kerrek, Johannes, chris, Jonathan, etc.. It has had a huge impact on how I look at many problems, and definitely on my approach to the language itself. It has actually been incredibly humbling. So I know all to well the whole learn-by-helping others.